# Python - Replacing many consecutive <script> tags with one "master" tag?

Tags: python, html

In many of our application's .htm files, we have Adobe RoboHelp generated references to Javascript files, like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="template/scripts/rh.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="template/scripts/common.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="template/scripts/topic.min.js"></script>
...and so on...
```

Having too many of these files increase download/unzip times, so we want to compact all of these .js files into one "master" file, and have these script references made into one reference.

I have the first finished by appending the contents of each .js file to a "new" .js file. To redo the references, I have been trying to write a Python application to automate it for thousands of files. For the second part, I wanted to use regular expressions to find/replace, but from what I've read, HTML is not a regular language, and thus cannot be fully and properly accepted by regular expressions.

My question is, if regexes are okay in this situation, how would I replace many `<script ...></script>` lines with a single, predefined line? If not, what are some other solutions I could look into?

Comment: You would have to put all of the javascript into one file, or use some kind of js bundler.

Comment: @marcusshep That step I already have done by appending each of the .js files into a single new one. At this point, I just need to have the .htm files reference the correct "new" .js file.

Comment: (in a python script) Iterate over each file that needs to be changed, remove all lines that contain the string `<script text=`, append the proper script tag to the file before the line `</html>`. There's no need for regex in this situation, with python this will be very simple.

Comment: That makes sense, I've been overthinking this. Thank you!